# SQL Server Query for last and average values

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to get "last value" for one group (Row id = 1)and "average value" for another group (Row id = 2).

I'm trying to write SQL Query in SQL Server.

Below is the data set and the expected output.

```
Name         ROWID  Type    Company   Date      KPI
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/01/2018   10
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/02/2018   20
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/03/2018   30
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/04/2018   NULL
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/05/2018   NULL
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/06/2018   NULL
Activity Plan   1   Low       MS    1/07/2018   NULL
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/01/2018   15
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/02/2018   25
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/03/2018   25
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/04/2018   NULL
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/05/2018   NULL
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/06/2018   NULL
Appointment     2   High      MS    1/07/2018   NULL
```

Expected Output

```
 Name         ROWID   Type  Company   Date     KPI   Value  
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/01/2018   10   10 
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/02/2018   20   20 
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/03/2018   30   30 
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/04/2018  NULL  30   last value
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/05/2018  NULL  30   Last Value
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/06/2018  NULL  30   Last Value
Activity Plan   1     Low    MS     1/07/2018  NULL  30   Last Value
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/01/2018   12   12 
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/02/2018   35   35 
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/03/2018   44   44 
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/04/2018   NULL 30.33  AVG Value
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/05/2018   NULL 30.33  AVG Value
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/06/2018   NULL 30.33  AVG Value
Appointment     2     High   MS     1/07/2018   NULL 30.33  AVG Value
```

My attempt:

*

```
select    f.name
           f.rowid,
           f.type,
           f.company,
           f.date,
           f.KPI,
           case when name ='Appointment' then avg( f2.KPI) 
          else max(f.KPI) OVER (PARTITION BY f.rowid order by f,date) end as result
   from table f 
inner join 
       table f2
 on f.rowid = f2.opwid
group by 
           f.name
           f.rowid,
           f.type,
           f.company,
           f.date,
           f.KPI
```

*

Comment: Could you at least format your question properly and explain what you've tried and what is not working yet?

Comment: Putting *** Urgent *** in your title is just going to get your post ignored (and you shouldn't be relying on stranger on a Q&A website to save your neck).

Comment: If the query is urgent, write a *proper* title and explanation in the question text. Otherwise you'll waste a *lot* of time as people start asking what you mean so they can help.

Comment: Asking for help with a query when you don't even post the query isn't helping either

Comment: If it is "urgent" take the time to provide the sample data in a consumable format and post what you've tried; you *might* get an answer quicker: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). You'll certainly have more user's be happier to answer, as we won't be to transform the data into a usable format (although at least it isn't an image).

Comment: BTW check the [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and the [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement. LAST_VALUE is available in all supported SQL Server versions, ie 2012 and later

Comment: That SQL is incomplete, but it's a start. Now, how about that **consumable** sample data, please? Thanks. (Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50061766/edit) your post, don't post it in the comments).

Comment: @SwethaJ since you already know about CASE and windowing functions, use AVG and LAST_VALUE. What was the problem with your query? What was the output?

Comment: @Rich Got to say, you made my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this to achieve your result:

```
select 
     [name]     =   [name]      
    ,[rowid]    =   [rowid] 
    ,[type]     =   [type]          
    ,[company]  =   [company]     
    ,[date]     =   [date]      
    ,[kpi]      =   [kpi]   
    ,[value]    =   iif([rowid] = 1, isnull([kpi], [lvalue].[value]), isnull([kpi], [avgvalue].[value]))    
from
    #urgent as  [u]
outer apply
    (
        select top 1 [value] = [kpi] from #urgent where [rowid] = 1 and [kpi] is not null order by [date] desc 
    ) as [lvalue]
outer apply
    (
        select [value] = avg([kpi]) from #urgent where [rowid] = 2  and [kpi] is not null
    ) as [avgvalue];
```

Full script: https://pastebin.com/fJQB6wyP

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(    select Name, ROWID, Type, Company, Date, KPI 
          , max(kpi) over (partition by ROWID) as max 
          , avg(kpi) over (partition by ROWID) as avg
     from urgent  
)
select Name, ROWID, Type, Company, Date, KPI, isnull(KPI, max) as Value 
from cte 
where ROWID = 1 
union all
select Name, ROWID, Type, Company, Date, KPI, isnull(KPI, avg) as Value 
from cte 
where ROWID = 2
```